# Проблема компиляции модулей в D

Tags: компиляция, d, ld

При попытке скомпилировать проект компилятор выдает ошибку:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_D5hello4nameFZAya", referenced from:
      __Dmain in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Error: linker exited with status 1
```

Команда для компиляции

```
dmd main.d
```

Операционная система: macOS 10.12.6

Файлы лежат в одной папке:

**main.d**

```
module main;

import std.stdio;
import hello;


void main()
{
    writeln(hello.name());
    writeln(name());
}
```

**hello.d**

```
module hello;

string name()
{
    return "hello.d";
}
```

Comment: @Abyx, ни слова в документации, я думал он сам по импортам подтягивает

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в команде для компиляции, правильно будет так

```
dmd main.d hello.d
```